# Viewport width issue on responsive mobile template

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, viewport

I am trying to convert a poorly designed template to a responsive design, found here:http://www.crhinc.com/about-mobile.html

Im having an issue where on desktop browser sized to mobile the template looks and works great, but on android and iphone, the page is larger than the viewport. i know i must be missing something, but as you can see, i have outlined the elements just to get try and see if i can find out whats in there that is stretching it outside the viewport and cause mobile phones to scroll from side to side but not desktop browsers.

i set the body up for 300px width just to see if i could find the rogue element, but put it back because it did not work. there are a few tables in the content, but all set to 100% width.

for some reason, it almost looks like the width in the desktop and on mobiles or not actually the same.

Jeff

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response, so that i can correct this for future assistance, should i copy all code, including the whole html page and css? I would like very much to a. help others that may be looking for answers, and b. help myself not be flagged like this.

Comment: See the text..."the *shortest* code necessary to reproduce it."

Comment: You only have one media query, create one more for phone sizes 400px and below. and remove your div wrapper.

Comment: I put it up to 500 just for trouble shooting, if i remove the wrapper div, the table goes full screen in desktop mode. how would i get around that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually think it is the viewport? Do you have the [viewport](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) set with the right content?

Maybe [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) could help.

Or is it just the CSS? In that case I would recommand you searching for `width` and such. Trying to find big numbers..

Setting a specified width should be for specified screen sizes. Otherwise make it max-width.

Comment: My viewport is this <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> i have searched the html and 2 css files for width, and anything above 400px, is set to 100% width.

Comment: Mhm, it's hard to give a solution since we have to almost gamble where the problem occurs.. Would love to help you further, but I don't know how.

Comment: Thank you, I am stumped too, I've been looking at this for 2 days and was hoping a fresh pair of eyes could see something i am missing.

Comment: One thing I try once in a while.. make a copy of the files, then delete element by element, and see when the problem doesn't occur anymore...
Since the issue seems to be only on your smartphone a simple f12 wouldn't do, hence the copy :) maybe use a subdomain to test :)